# SLFJ4 bridge for the Maven logger

Tags: maven-3, slf4j, logback

I'm writing a Maven 3.x plugin and want to log with SLF4J & Logback.

I found some SLF4J bindings for the Maven Logger:

- http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-maven-slf4j/index.html
- https://bitbucket.org/peachjean/slf4j-mojo

However, these seem to be SLF4J bindings but I believe what I need is a bridge for the Maven Logger i.e. to bridge/route all Maven log statements to SLF4J and use LogBack binding with logback.xml config.

Answer (score 4):

You can use SLF4J directly from Maven plugin since Maven 3.1:

> The standard Maven distribution, from Maven 3.1.0 onward, uses the
>   SLF4J API for logging combined with the SLF4J Simple implementation.
>   Future versions may use a more advanced implementation, but we chose
>   to start simple.

No bridges, bindings, etc. needed.

Source:
    https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin should log through [`Log`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-plugin-api/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/logging/class-use/Log.html) class. Logback is not required. Just forward all your logs to SLF4J and add [jcabi-maven-slf4j](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-maven-slf4j/index.html) dependency to the plugin. That's it.

Comment: Please explain why would he add that jar? Maven 3.1+ supports `slf4j-simple`.